# don't return column from select?

Tags: mysql, select

First, let me say thanks in advance. I'm brand new to mysql and can't seem to find an answer to this question.

I have a small query in which I issue a select with various columns. Two of the columns are different tables and denote a dept number. When the query runs it returns both instances of the dept number, but I only want one. I've been looking for info on how to control this or if I can control it.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT d.dept_no, e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name, f.dept_no
FROM departments d, employees e, dept_emp f
WHERE d.dept_no = f.dept_no AND e.emp_no = f.emp_no AND d.dept_no = 'd009' AND e.gender = 'F';
```

Here are some results:

```
dept_no emp_no  first_name  last_name   dept_no
d009    10011   Mary    Sluis   d009
d009    10049   Basil   Tramer  d009
d009    10088   Jungsoon    Syrzycki    d009
d009    10098   Sreekrishna Servieres   d009
d009    10112   Yuichiro    Swick   d009
d009    10128   Babette Lamba   d009
d009    10154   Abdulah Thibadeau   d009
```

Comment: @Rahul - thank you :)

Comment: @paulsm4, No issue; Welcome Brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the one that you dont want.

example

```
    SELECT d.dept_no, e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name 
    FROM  departments d, employees e, dept_emp f 
    WHERE d.dept_no = f.dept_no AND e.emp_no = f.emp_no AND d.dept_no = 'd009' AND e.gender = 'F';
```

You dont need to select the column to use it for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the particular column from your select clause (OR) use a column alias for better redability like below. Also notice that I have modified your query to use explicite join syntax rather than old style implicit join syntax.

```
SELECT d.dept_no as Department_dept_no, 
e.emp_no, 
e.first_name, 
e.last_name, 
f.dept_no as dept_emp_deptno
FROM departments d 
JOIN dept_emp f ON d.dept_no = f.dept_no 
JOIN employees e ON e.emp_no = f.emp_no 
WHERE d.dept_no = 'd009' 
AND e.gender = 'F';
```

Comment: rahul -- I think I just did it...let me know if I misunderstood how to do it right....